# Installed linux-image-686-pae and now my second monitor won't work

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, debian, linux-kernel, pae

I just installed `linux-image-686-pae` on my Debian system and the PAE kernel effectively increased the memory limit.

However for some reason my dual monitors both show the same image, instead of an expanded desktop. When I use GRUB to boot the normal kernel, the second monitor once again expands the desktop. What's going on?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the display driver in the PAE version of the kernel, assuming the normal kernel is the exact same version as the PAE one.  [You should file a bug.](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the bigmem kernel instead.